# Line numbering in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

at the moment I evaluate some libraries for PDF creations in Java. PDFBox is at the moment one of the libraries I want to use. In my use case I want to give every chapter a new line numbering. I tried and searched a lot around, but I really have no idea how I can archieve this. Does anyone has some suggestions? Thank you very much for everything!

[image]

Comment: Pdfbox is low level. You can output numbers wherever you want. There is no chapter concept.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help. Here's how to generate a menu and sub-menu (along with main menu and sub-menu numbering):

Use this class:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PdfExample
{
    private String pdfFileName = "";

    public PdfExample(String pdfFileName)
    {
        this.pdfFileName=pdfFileName;

        //creating new document:
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage blancPage = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(blancPage);
        PDFont font_TIMES_ROMAN = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;

        try
        {
            PDPageContentStream fileStream = new PDPageContentStream(document,blancPage);
            fileStream.setFont( font_TIMES_ROMAN, 12 );

            fileStream.beginText();
            fileStream.newLineAtOffset(50,735);
            fileStream.showText("Chapter numbering example:");
            fileStream.endText();

            //veeery simple positioning configuration:
            int mainMenuPosition_Y = 700;
            int mainMenuPosition_X = 50;
            int lineSpacing = 30;
            int numberOfMainMenus = 6;
            int subMenuLeftMargin = mainMenuPosition_X+20;

            HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> subMenu = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList>();
            //I'm adding some sample submenu's:
            subMenu.put(1,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Item 1","Item 2","Item 3")));     // firstOne Main Menu
            subMenu.put(2,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Item 1","Item 2","Item 3")));  // second Main Menu
            subMenu.put(5,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Item 1","Item 2")));          // 5th

            for(int i = 1 ; i <= numberOfMainMenus ; i++)
            {
                fileStream.beginText();
                fileStream.newLineAtOffset(mainMenuPosition_X,mainMenuPosition_Y);
                fileStream.showText(i+". Main Menu");
                fileStream.endText();

                if(subMenu.get(i)!=null)
                {
                    for(int w = 0; w < subMenu.get(i).size();w++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(subMenu.get(i).get(w));
                        fileStream.beginText();
                        fileStream.newLineAtOffset(subMenuLeftMargin,(mainMenuPosition_Y-=15));
                        fileStream.showText(i+"."+(w+1)+" "+subMenu.get(i).get(w));
                        fileStream.endText();
                    }
                }
                mainMenuPosition_Y-=lineSpacing;
            }

            fileStream.close();
            document.save(pdfFileName+".pdf");
            document.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end
}
```

and then just:

```
PdfExample document = new PdfExample("SimpleExample");
```

This code will generate something like this:

[SimpleExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj7dF.png)

And remember about 'project structure libraries' in your IDE:

[Project Structure Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgMGw.png)

I hope I helped a little bit ;]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But unfortunately this is not exactly what I want. Sorry for my poor description. I added an example to be clearer about my requirement.